# Drupal 7 : Render add to cart form in external app ( with Services )

Tags: web-services, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

i'm a beginner on Drupal, and i have to retrieve data of drupal website to display product on Windows 8 app.

I use Services module (REST) and Commerce Services ressources ( https://drupal.org/project/commerce_services ).

It's easy to retrieve informations of ressources products, product-display, nodes... but i can't find how to render "add to cart" button on my external app.

However, in the module description, we can read :
 "It also supports pseudo-entities such as product displays and shopping carts to make it easier to render Add to Cart forms and manipulate cart contents remotely".

Someone have any idea how to do this ?

thank a lot !

ps: sorry for my bad english :s